# How to do this using html/javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to create an array to map with calendar months. But, I am weak with javascript, so I tried this, help with ways to improve.

Tried this

```
   <script>
       function getMonthFromString(mon){
           var d = Date.parse(mon + "1, 2012");
           if(!isNAN(d)){
               return new Date(d).getMonth()+ 1;
           }
           return -1;
       }
   </script>


</head>
<body>
    <select>
            <option value="1">January</option>
            <option value="2">February</option>
            <option value="3">March</option>
            <option value="4">April</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">June</option>
            <option value="7">July</option>
            <option value="8">August</option>
            <option value="9">September</option>
            <option value="10">October</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>


</body>
```

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First point**: Your select should have numeric options, not the name of the months.

**Second point**: Your `<select>` element should have a event listener, that should be attached using jQuery.

**Third point**: When a month is choosed, you should display it in a div.

Your code could look like below. In the current example, I'm using jQuery 3.3.1. You can read the docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/).

```js
function getMonthFromNumber(e) {
  const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April","May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  // Using jQuery selector to add the month to the div
  $(".selected").text(months[e.target.value-1])

  /* The e.target.value is the value contained in the
  select option clicked. As you can see, each <option>
  has a different value */

}

// Attaching the event listener to the select element
$("#select").on("change",getMonthFromNumber);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <select id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
  </select>
  <div class="selected"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: when i put the function in the html, it doesn't give me when select 1, print january

Comment: @PTL, have you added the jQuery to your code? Look at the first tag on the html